# remove blank rows in the CSV file using NiFi

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

I want to achieve a simple use case to remove any blank row found in the CSV file. How Can I achieve this using NiFi?

I have CSV File as follows: (Plz see Attached Screenshot showing which row needs to be removed)
[image]

I want to remove the first **Blank Row** in the csv just above the headers using NiFi. Please, any suggestion is much appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: What does this have to do with regex?

Comment: @emsimpson92 In NiFi you can use regex or any other way to delete the blank row. I want to know ways to achieve my use case.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the text of your flow file. Is it only first line empty?

Comment: @daggett I want to remove the first row of the CSV please see the screenshot attached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `ReplaceText` processor which replaces `\A\n|\n*\s*(?=\n)` with `''` (empty replacement value). The search regex looks for:

- `\A\n` - beginning of the content immediately followed by a newline *OR*
- `\n*\s*(?=\n)` - newline (0 or more) followed by whitespace (0 or more) followed by a newline (not captured using lookahead group)

**Update**

Not sure why this was downvoted or did not work for some user, as I just [created a template](https://gist.github.com/alopresto/c1b5362aa59fa30b33996da46d569bd5) and it worked exactly as described.

[image: Overview of NiFi flow]

[image: Configuration of GenerateFlowFile processor]

[image: Configuration of ReplaceText processor]

```
2019-01-08 12:25:27,642 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.processors.standard.LogAttribute LogAttribute[id=2f22d047-0168-1000-47b0-9ec963e65367] logging for flow file StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=6c9cc388-19c8-4b98-9970-6a6e3979e4ee,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1546979126561-1, container=default, section=1], offset=152, length=50],offset=0,name=6c9cc388-19c8-4b98-9970-6a6e3979e4ee,size=50]
--------------------------------------------------
Standard FlowFile Attributes
Key: 'entryDate'
    Value: 'Tue Jan 08 12:25:27 PST 2019'
Key: 'lineageStartDate'
    Value: 'Tue Jan 08 12:25:27 PST 2019'
Key: 'fileSize'
    Value: '50'
FlowFile Attribute Map Content
Key: 'filename'
    Value: '6c9cc388-19c8-4b98-9970-6a6e3979e4ee'
Key: 'path'
    Value: './'
Key: 'uuid'
    Value: '6c9cc388-19c8-4b98-9970-6a6e3979e4ee'
--------------------------------------------------
header1,header2,header3
A1,A2,A3
B1,B2,B3
C1,C2,C3
```

Comment: It went to failure. CAn you provide more detail? Like what will be the replacement strategy?

Comment: I've provided a template, screenshots of configuration and flow statistics, and log output verifying this works.

Comment: If this causes failure for you, there may be other characters on your "blank" line. Please provide the CSV file in plaintext format, not as a screenshot in Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation.